# MySqlDataReader.GetStream() throws IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql.data

So I'm using the MySql.Data package for my .NET Core project and store password hashes and salts (of type `byte[]`) as `varbinary()` to the database. When selecting the password hash and salt from a user I need a way to convert the result back to a byte array. Given this sample code

```
Stream passwordHashStream = dbDataReader.GetStream(0);
byte[] passwordHash;
                        
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    await passwordHashStream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
    passwordHash = memoryStream.ToArray();
}
```

the first line will throw this exception

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Data index must be a valid index in
> the field    at
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Interceptors.ExceptionInterceptor.Throw(Exception
> exception)    at
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Throw(Exception ex)    at
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.Throw(Exception ex)    at
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.GetBytes(Int32 i, Int64
> fieldOffset, Byte[] buffer, Int32 bufferoffset, Int32 length)    at
> System.Data.Common.DbDataReader.GetStream(Int32 ordinal)    at
> Infrastructure.Persistence.Repositories.UsersRepository.<>c.<b__1_0>d.MoveNext()
> in
> /.../Infrastructure/Persistence/Repositories/UsersRepository.cs:line
> 60

although the reader contains the correct database results as you can see here down below (password is 32 bytes, hash is 16 bytes)

[image]

The error was reported in 2018

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=93374

and has a verified status. Are there any good solutions / workarounds on how to solve it? I don't want to use the `GetBytes` method because it requires me to pass in the length of the byte array and I would like to stay independent from that.

Comment: Does `GetItem(0)` cast to byte[] work?

Comment: sorry, this method does not exist. `dbDataReader.GetItem(0)`

Comment: My bad, wrong namespace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uninstall MySql.Data and replace it with [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/).

(Disclosure: I'm the reporter of the [MySql bug you found](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=93374) and the primary contributor to [MySqlConnector](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector).)

As well as fixing that issue [and many other bugs](https://mysqlconnector.net/tutorials/migrating-from-connector-net/#fixed-bugs), MySqlConnector adds true async I/O support and performance improvements.

> I don't want to use the `GetBytes` method because it requires me to pass in the length of the byte array and I would like to stay independent from that.

If you don't want to switch libraries, a little-known feature of `GetBytes` (supported by both MySql.Data and MySqlConnector) is that passing in a `null` buffer returns the needed length, so you don't need to hard-code it:

```cs
// get the length of the column and allocate a buffer
var length = dbDataReader.GetBytes(0, 0, null, 0, 0);
var passwordHash = new byte[length];

// fill the buffer from the column
dbDataReader.GetBytes(0, 0, passwordHash, 0, passwordHash.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
public static async Task<MemoryStream> ToMemoryStream(this Stream stream)
    {
      var memStream = stream as MemoryStream;
      if (memStream == null)
      {
        memStream = new MemoryStream();
        await stream.CopyToAsync(memStream);
      }
      return memStream;
    }
```

Comment: sorry, I don't understand your solution. Could you explain it a little bit?

Comment: Asy function should call from asy function .I am not aware the function where you call CopyToAsync